# A soft question on latex editor software

Tags: editors

Any good WYSIWYG based latex editor software which might be useful for making instructional videos, say, in mathematics or other subjects?

Comment: What is your question? Please re-edit and add more context.

Comment: Some editors as Gummi can show live previews but of complete LaTeX documents.  This is not the case of this site, that  does not use Mathjax  (and moreover, is off-topic here).

Comment: @Fran, I have edited my question. You can post this comment as an answer. Actually, I was looking for an editor with live previews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a comprehensive revision of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) in this site with a somewhat standardized checklist of features, and one of them is the "Built-in Output Viewer".

Other "must have" for your purpose could be the "Syntax Highlighting" and maybe othes and "Code Completion", "SyncTeX", etc.

Among these, Gummi could be a good option because is very simple, but unlike many others editors with built-in viewers, can be configured to compile automatically every x seconds, so that the changes in code are showed almost in real time with small documents. But feel free to compare to others of the list. In most cases is free. `:)`